# Update Mongodb with node js express and PUG(JADE)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to add an edit page where I can change the name field in the mongodb.But I am having problems with the routing, can anyone please help? here is the routing:

```
router.put('/edit', function(req, res) {
user.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id},
                 {
        name: req.body.name
     });   
  });
```

And here is edit.pug

```
extends layout

block content
  .main.container.clearfix
    h1 Editing #{name}'s profile!
    form(method="POST", action="/edit")
     input(type="hidden", name="_method", value="PUT")
     p Name:
      input#name.form-control(type='text', value='#{name}')
     p
      input(type="submit")
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there's a few things I see here I think I can help clear up:

`user.findByIdAndUpdate` 
- doesn't take an object for the first argument, just the _id.
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate

`req.params` - is connected to the route this callback is attached, so in your route you need to put a `/:id` to express that the value can change but will be available as req.params.id. Basically your route should look like `router.put('/edit/:id', function(req, res) {...`
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters

You may also want look into the `options` argument of the `findByIdAndUpdate` method, because by default it returns the original document from its lookup not the one saved to the db after the updates have been applied.

so your node code should look like this:

```
router.put('/edit/:id', function(req, res) { 
user.findByIdAndUpdate(
     req.params.id, // Which _id mongoose should search for
     { name: req.body.name }, //Updates to apply to the found document.
     { new: true }); // This tells mongoose to return the new updates back from the db   
  });
```